# Unable to add item to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am making a small calculator program because i'm bored, and i ran into a issue where i can't add item named `Test` with value `awnser` and i am unsure why, please help

```py
question = []
awnslog = {
  'None': 0
}

while True:
  Inp = int(input('>> '))
  Inp2 = str(input('>> '))
  Inp3 = int(input('>> '))
  question.insert(0, Inp3)
  question.insert(0, Inp2)
  question.insert(0, Inp)
  if '*' or 'x' in question:
    print('*')
    print(question[0]*question[2])
    awnser = question[0]*[question[2]
    awnslog['Test'] = awnser # <--- Issue
    print(awnslog)
```

Comment: `if '*' in question or 'x' in question:`

Comment: @Barmar, both work

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket: `awnser = question[0]*[question[2]`

Comment: They aren't the same.

Comment: looks like some syntax error in `awnser = question[0]*[question[2]`

Comment: @BTables No, it's an extra `[` before `question[2]`

Comment: `if '*' or 'x' in question:` is wrong, that conditional is **always true**. Python isn't english, the `in question` doesn't distribute over the logical connetive. You need to use `if '*' in question or 'x' in question: ...`

Comment: You could also use `if question[1] in ['*', 'x']:`

Comment: I don't understand why you'er using `.insert`. Why not just `question = [Inp, Inp2, Inp3]`?

Comment: @Barmar it depends on how the OP wants to use the results. `question[0]*[question[2]]` is completely valid, albeit a little odd.

Comment: @BTables He's making a calculator. Multiplying a list can't possibly be what he intends.

Comment: @BTables And he didn't write it that way in the `print()` line before the dictionary assignment.

Comment: To the OP: What is the specific problem you're having? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Barmar One line is to print a raw value and one is to save it. There is a large potential difference in the application there. The dictionary is clearly meant to be a log of past calculations(implemented incorrectly), I think we can agree you'd want a list instead of a single value for that...

Comment: The logic is also not working because in case we have a match in the first iteration of the while loop the match will stay active all the time, because the question list is not cleared.

Comment: @BTables You might want a list of answers, but why would you want to turn this answer into a list of one of the operands, instead of the result of the multiplication?

Comment: No it isn't. If `question[0] == 3` and `question[2] == 5`, the result of that is `[5, 5, 5]` @BTables

Comment: You're thinking of `[question[0]*question[2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for failure is probably the `SyntaxError` here:

```
awnser = question[0]*[question[2]
```

It should have been `awnser = question[0]*question[2]` (Note the `[` before `question[2]`. Also `insert` is expensive operation as it shifts all the elements in a `list` by one place. Also you are doing nothing in `awnslog` as everytime you add new entry with `Test` the older entry will be overwritten, so I am not sure what's the intention of having `awsnlog`. Here is one of the approach;

```
awnslog = {
  'None': 0
}

while True:
    question = []
    Inp = question.append(int(input('First Number: ')))
    Inp2 = question.append(str(input('Operation: ')))
    Inp3 = question.append(int(input('Second Nummber: ')))
    if question[1] in ['*', 'x', 'X']:
        print(question[0]*question[2])
        awnser = question[0]*question[2]
        awnslog['Test'] = awnser
        print(awnslog)
```